# How to set default month and day in the datetimepicker?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have searched online and i only managed to find codes to set the year month and day.

```
dateTimePicker2.Value = new DateTime(2017,12,31);
```

I tried using the custom format and it does not seem to work

```
dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "DD/MM";
dateTimePicker2.Value = new DateTime(12,31);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create `DateTime` object only from day and month. `DateTime` simply doesn't have this kind of constructor. [DateTime Constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

So you need to go with some kind of "workaround"
 -  Use "dummy" year and when you need to use a date - use only `Month` and `Day` properties.

```
var dummyYear = 2000;
dateTimePicker2.Value = new DateTime(dummyYear, 12, 31);
```

Another workaround will be to use `ParseExact` method which will create `DateTime` based on the format you are using "dd/MM"

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("31/12", "dd/MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
dateTimePicker2.Value = date; // 12/31/2017
```

Notice that when you did not provide a year - current year will be used.
Another notice: `DD` is invalid format for days it should be lower case "dd"

Comment: Hi fabio i tried the parseExact method but parseExact has error and they said does not exist in the datetime

Comment: `ParseExact` should work, can you show what did you tried?

Comment: I have updated answer there was a typo - please try again. Do not use copy/paste when writing code ;)

Comment: hi i got this error                                                                                         
 The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

Comment: Check updated answer, as I said before Do not use copy/paste when writing code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot partially set the date without a year, it's not valid.

What you cand do is specify the month and date in code as "default" values, and get the current year programmtically (or whatever year you want), and use that value for the year.

Answer (score 0):

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM";
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.